# How do I extract a specific attribute from a list of elements that are all the same

Tags: c#, selenium, attributes, css-selectors

Our company has a report that shows bar graphs. The color of all the bars are gray except for 2 bars that are blue and green respectively as seen below:

[image: Bar Graph]

Here is what the elements look like:

[image: Bar Graph Elements]

Now the blue and green graphs can appear anywhere on the x-axis.
I am writing my selenium test cases in C# and I want to check that the highlighted elements are present on the page.

Here is how I've defined my element selector variable

```
private readonly By barGraphAverage = By.CssSelector("rect[fill='#0373bc']");
```

and I wrote a method to check if that element exists

```
public string getBarGraph()
{
    return base.Browser.FindElementOrNull(barGraphAverage).Text;
}
```

This is how I'm calling it in my test class

```
Assert.IsTrue(getBarGraph());
```

Comment: Just search for the item you have highlighted in second image.

Comment: Have you tried using CSS selectors? I would imagine they could access the fill attribute on the element...

Comment: You probably need to state what the actual question is. You have code but you don't state what error you are getting or what the result is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have most things set up correctly except that you are using `Assert.IsTrue()` but `getBarGraph()` returns a `string` when it needs to return a `boolean`. If you change it to something like the below, it should work.

```
public boolean getBarGraph()
{
    return (driver.FindElements(barGraphAverage).Count > 0);
}
```